# Why this.getClass().getName() will produce different result from StackTraceElement.getClassName()?

Tags: java

My question is why the code, this.getClass().getName(), in the ElementModel constructor will produce BaseModel$1 as the result instead of ElementModel?

Also, you will notice that the same code in the BaseModel constructor will give you CellModel.

Simply put, I expect the code will give me ElementModel when it is called in the ElementModel constructor. BaseModel when it is called in the BaseModel constructor. However, such is not the case.

Also, you will notice that in the method demo2, the code st.getClassName() will produce ElementMode, which is the expected result.

Therefore I am very confused here. Anyone can shed any light on this will be greatly appreciated.

The base:

```
public class BaseModel<E> {

    protected ElementModel<E> addedElements;

    public BaseModel() {
       String msg = this.getClass().getName();        
 System.out.println("BaseModel::BaseModel.......this.getClass.getName(): "+msg);
       addedElements = new ElementModel<E>(){};
    }
}
```

The element model:

```
public class ElementModel<E> {
public ElementModel() {
    String msg = this.getClass().getName();
    System.out.println("ElementModel::ElementModel.......this.getClass.getName(): "+msg);
}

public void add(E e) {
    demo1();
    demo2();
}

private void demo1() {

    System.out.println("\n==================== Begin demo1 ========================");
    String msg = this.getClass().getName();
    System.out.println("ElementModel::demo1.......this.getClass.getName(): "+msg);;
    msg = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    System.out.println("ElementModel::demo1.......this.getClass.getSimpleName(): "+msg);
    msg = this.getClass().getTypeName();
    System.out.println("ElementModel::demo1.......this.getClass.getTypeName(): "+msg);
    msg = this.getClass().toGenericString();
    System.out.println("ElementModel::demo1.......this.getClass.toGenericString: "+msg);
    StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    int i=0;
    for(StackTraceElement st : ste) 
    {
        System.out.println(i+++": "+st.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("==================== End demo1 ========================\n");
}

private void demo2() {

    System.out.println("\n**************** Begin demo2 **************************");
    String msg = this.getClass().getName();
    System.out.println("ElementModel::demo2.......this.getClass.getName(): "+msg);
    StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for(StackTraceElement st : ste)    {
        if (st.getMethodName().equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
            System.out.println("ElementModel::demo2.......st.getClassName: "+st.getClassName());
            System.out.println("ElementModel::demo2.......Thread.class.getName: "+Thread.class.getName());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("**************** End demo2 **************************\n");

}
}
```

The cell model:

```
public class CellModel<E> extends BaseModel<E> {

public CellModel() {
    String msg = this.getClass().getName();
    System.out.println("CellModel::CellModel.......this.getClass.getName(): "+msg);

    addedElements.add(null);
}
}
```

The main test:

```
public class TheTest extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    System.out.println("test");
    CellModel<String> s = new CellModel<>();

    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new ElementModel<E>(){};
```

creates an anonymous inner class extending `ElementModel`. The constructor of `ElementModel` prints the name of the actual class, not of `ElementModel` itself. You should have written

```
new ElementModel<E>();
```

**EDIT** The name of the anonymous inner class is `BaseModel$1` because it is an anonymous inner class of `BaseModel`.

Comment: If you look at the constructor of BaseModel, you will notice that ElementModel is initialized there. However, my question is why this.getClass().getName(), which is called inside the ElementModel's constructor, will NOT give the name ElementModel?

Comment: I answered that in my very first sentence. When you try the fix I provided you will see for yourself.

Comment: I am looking for a fix, I am looking for why.

Comment: I have provided you with both the explanation and the fix. If you look at the constructor of `BaseModel` you will notice that the code I quoted is located there.

Comment: That's right, `new ElementModel<E>(){}` in the base constructor is causing the issue here.

Comment: @Tania A note on your design - base classes should never be aware of classes that are derived from them. If you absolutely need to have a linked list kind of model, consider changing the reference in base to `protected final BaseModel<E> addedElements;`. The remaining changes will follow naturally.

Comment: @Timir I add the keyword final and the code, this.getClass().getName(), inside the ElementModel still produce the result as BaseModel$1

Comment: I thought that doubt was already answered - it's the line `new ElementModel<E>(){}` that's causing it.

Comment: I don't know why people post questions here if they're not going to read the answers.